# Set border width for mintty window on cygwin/windows 10

Tags: cygwin, mintty

When running mintty on Cygwin with Windows 10, if I have two windows open that partially overlap, and neither has the focus, the bottom and non-scrollbar borders are invisible, and the text of both windows runs together.

Is there a way to make these borders a little wider ?

Comment: It will be helpful if you add a screenshot of your issue.

Comment: Setting a border (width) would be more than helpful. Hard to believe this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

In your `~/.minttyrc` file add a line that says:

`Padding=8`

This adds an 8px border on the inside of the window frame for all subsequently launched mintty terminals. Of course you can change the `8` to whatever size appeals to your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I use a workaround: I assign a different background colour to each window. This can be done via the "Options" context menu each time you open a new window.

However, you can also automate. I've added the code below to my ".bashrc" to select the "next available" colour. The list of colours is simply a list of RGB values.

```
# Set the next available background colour
for COLOUR in 0,0,0 100,0,0 0,100,0 0,0,100
do
    PIDFILE=/var/run/mintty-bgcolour-${COLOUR}.pid
    PID=`[ -e $PIDFILE ] && cat $PIDFILE`

    if ! kill -0 "$PID" 2>/dev/null
    then
        echo $$ > $PIDFILE
        echo -ne '\e]11;'$COLOUR'\a'
        trap 'rm -f '$PIDFILE EXIT
        break
    fi
done
unset COLOUR PIDFILE
```

Another workaround is to set the transparency in "options" on the window to, say, "Medium" and then check the box "Opaque when focussed".  This sort of gives you a different background colour on all the windows except the active one.

Comment: I've written a similar function to do this in https://gist.github.com/ivan/cbb333d48e19bf8fc025c599dccbd542 with 8 colors.